Is a spirit summoned with the Find Greater Steed spell affected by the Divine Word spell?
The Divine Word spell description says:

Regardless of its current hit points, a celestial, an elemental, a
fey, or a fiend that fails its save is forced back to its plane of
origin (if it isn't there already) and can't return to your current
plane for 24 hours by any means short of a wish spell.

Is a celestial spirit summoned with the Find Greater Steed spell affected? I'm not sure if it has a plane of origin.

Yes, it is affected by Divine Word.
From the introduction of the Monster Manual:

Celestials are creatures native to the Upper Planes. Many of them are the servants of deities, employed as messengers or agents in the mortal realm and throughout the planes. Celestials are good by nature, so the exceptional celestial who strays from a good alignment is a horrifying rarity. Celestials include angels, couatls, and pegasi.

The spirit summoned via Find Greater Steed belongs to one of the Upper Planes, if it is a celestial, per description: hence, if it fails its saving throw it will return to its home plane, whatever it is.

Does find greater steed cease to work if recast, or does it just summon a different creature?

@ThomasMarkov It seems to me that if you cast it again before the 24 hours after the divine word casting, then it fails. FGS allows the caster to dismiss the bond with current creature for summoning another one, but it seems that the steed has to be on caster's plane to be dismissed, per description.
